# how to use dynamo db with laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-dynamodb

Hello I am new to dynamo db and laravel. After searching on the internet I found so many ways to setup the dynamo db for laravel and I tried each of them. but after setup the for using the dynamo db in laravel I cant found any tutorial or any sample codes so that I can use it further.
some sites links which I used for dynamo db setup:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel

https://github.com/baopham/laravel-dynamodb

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php

http://www.techigniter.in/tutorials/dynamodb-session-driver-for-laravel-5/

there are more sites also, all using their own different methods but did not helped me enough.

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: If you are asking for learning more about coding for dynamo DB, it's best to refer the official docs.... https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Introduction.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's very simple actually. 
You can use this SDK for Laravel: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel

This link can help you understand how to use it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32594321/9845807

```
use AWS;
use Config;
public function dynamoDBConnect()
    {
        //Fetching credentials for DynamDB
        $config =  Config::get('aws');

        //Inserting value with tableName: "Logs" and columnName: "userId"
        $client = AWS::createClient('DynamoDb');
        $iterator = $client->getIterator('Query', array(
            'TableName'     => 'Logs',
            'KeyConditions' => array(
                'userId' => array(
                    'AttributeValueList' => array(
                        array('N' => '1202')
                    ),
                    'ComparisonOperator' => 'EQ'
                )
            )
        ));

        //Fetching the records.
        $result = $client->getItem(array(
            'ConsistentRead' => true,
            'TableName' => 'Logs',
            'Key'       => array(
                'userId'   => array('N' => '1201'),
                'Name'    => array('S' => 'Name string')
            )
        ));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 actively supported packages that (can) serve as service providers for Laravel:

- https://github.com/baopham/laravel-dynamodb
- https://github.com/kitar/laravel-dynamodb

Both have usage examples and provide options to create models that can use Eloquent methods, or to use a query builder.

Answer (score 0):

Full Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.PHP.html

Following method will connect to DynamoDB and retrieve data.
Change ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY, REGION, TABLE_NAME as yours.

My DynamoDB Data is like,
    {'2019-11-05':'12:30-13:00', '2019-11-05':'13:30-14:00'}

```
public function getDataFromDynamoDb() {
$credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY);

$client = new Aws\Sdk([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => REGION,
    'credentials' => $credentials
]);

$dynamodb = $client->createDynamoDb();
$marshaler = new Marshaler();

$tableName = 'TABLE_NAME';

$eav = $marshaler->marshalJson('{":Date": "2019-11-05"}');

$params = [
    'TableName' => $tableName,
    'KeyConditionExpression' => '#Date = :Date',
    'ExpressionAttributeNames'=> [ '#Date' => 'Date' ],
    'ExpressionAttributeValues'=> $eav
];

try {

    $result = $dynamodb->query($params);

    foreach ($result['Items'] as $marketData) {
        echo $marshaler->unmarshalValue($marketData['Date']) . ': ' .
            $marshaler->unmarshalValue($marketData['Value']) . "\n";
    }

} catch (DynamoDbException $e) {
    echo "Unable to query:\n";
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}}
```